# Ruby debugger won't step over

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-debug

using ruby-debug in rspec (through rspec -d), the debugger refuses to step over statements when I execute "next"

It seems to always step into the statement

```
debugger
params[:appointment][:user_id] = 
  User.where(email: appointment_params[:user_id]).pluck(:id).first if appointment_params[:user_id].to_i == 0
params[:appointment][:country_id] = 
  Country.where(name: appointment_params[:country_id]).pluck(:id).first if appointment_params[:country_id].to_i == 0

@appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
```

when I hit "n" and press enter, it steps into the User.where statement

I have no idea what might be causing this, any ideas?

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoint? What's the test/implementation code? Please provide more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely shouldn't be using `ruby-debug` and should upgrade to a more recent debugger.

Switch to [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) if you're using ruby 1.9.x or to [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) if using ruby 2.x and your problem should be gone. If you switch to `byebug`, don't use the `-d` flag, it will only affect performance and it doesn't provide any benefits.

Comment: Switching from "debugger" to "byebug" fixed this for me in Ruby 2.0.  Thanks.

Comment: It's true that there are far better debuggers